# Cloud Service Providers and Very Large Data Transfers

Tags: cloud, data-migration

Which cloud providers accept the shipping of disks with very large amounts of data (say, several Terabytes) for data migration (instead of having to transfer massive quantities of data over wires)?

I know that AWS currently offers this kind of service; even so, I was not able to get answers for this question with respect to Azure, Force.com, AppEngine, and Rackspace Cloud.

I am currently focused on these 4 providers, but info on others is also welcome!

Answer (score 1):

This article from Feb says that Microsoft is evaluating such a service http://searchstorage.techtarget.com.au/news/38951-Microsoft-evaluating-bulk-import-service-for-Azure

Have not been able to find anything newer.

Comment: I couldn't find anything either newer either, thanks for your response anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to update the post with advancements which have made fast data transfer possible after the question was asked back in 2010. Microsoft Azure offers following solutions for such scenarios -

1. Import / Export service - Interestingly ( :) ) you need to ship data using hard disk to Azure data centers. The entire process of using this service is documented here - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/storage-import-export-service/
2. Express Route - Private fiber network connectivity between on-premises and cloud infrastructure enables data to take the express way. This service does not use the public internet infrastructure, rather connects the Azure infrastructure directly to your WAN / via Exchange provider. Details of this service could be accessed in the documentation - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/expressroute-introduction/

Express route service though uses wire it is promised to be faster than transferring data over the public internet.